# How to swap first two items of a list in racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to write a function that takes a list and returns the same list with its first two elements swapped for instance given '(a b c d e f) it should return '(b a c d e f), I have managed to return the first two items swapped however it puts the rest of the elements in a list '(b a (c d e f)),also is there a simple way of doing this other than how I have done it.

```js
(define swap-two (λ (l)
                   (cond
                     ((empty? l) 0)
                     ((< (length l) 2) "less than two")
                     ((>= (length l) 2) (append (list (cadr l) (car l) (cddr l))))
                     (#t l))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simplify the solution, for starters you don't need so many cases, either the list has >= 2 elements, or not.

In Racket we can leverage the intuitively named `first` and `second` procedures for obtaining the first and second elements in a list, and the elements after that can be obtained with the not-so-intuitive `cddr` procedure.

The last step is to just `cons` everything together, to build a proper list. You were using `(append (list ...))`, that's why the last part appeared inside a list. Better spend some time familiarizing yourself with how `cons`, `list` and `append` work. This is what I mean:

```
(define swap-two
  (λ (lst)
    (if (< (length lst) 2)
        "less than two"
        (cons (second lst)
              (cons (first lst)
                    (cddr lst))))))
```

It works as expected:

```
(swap-two '(a b c d e f))
=> '(b a c d e f)
```